# Алгоритм столкновения на плоскости

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, typescript

#### Описание

Есть вот такая структура:

```ts
/**
 * Координата в плоскости
 */
interface Poind2D {
    x: Number;
    y: Number;
}

/**
 * Вектор в плоскости
 */
interface Vector2D {
    begin: Poind2D;
    end: Poind2D;
}

/**
 * Объект с границами
 */
class Subject {
    collider: Vector2D;
}
```

Потом у меня есть 2 экземпляры класса Subject.

```ts
const subject1 = new Subject();
const subject2 = new Subject();
```

Визуально можно представить так:

[image]

То есть, мы точно знаем, что у Subject свойство `collider.begin` это координата левого-нижнего угла, а `collider.end` - правого-верхнего. Но мы не знаем какой из этих Subject-ов где находится, какой левее, какой выше...

#### Вопрос

**Как проверить столкновение между этими объектами наиболее оптимальным способом?**
Столкновение — это когда прямоугольники пересекаются или соприкасаются (как на рисунке). Один прямоугольник в другом не считается столкновением.

Comment: В JS я не специалист, но одно могу сказать точно - это не вектора. Вектора не имеют начальной и конечной точки. Они имеют только направление и длину.

Comment: Скорее можно назвать "путём". Он имеет начальную и конечную точку, идёт из A в B кратчайшей траекторией.

Comment: @mister_svinia ну имея начальную и конечную точку мы можем считать угол наклона и длину. Опишите решение этим способом если вам так удобнее.

Comment: а почему если это именно *вектора*, нельзя сравнить четверти?

Comment: @mister_svinia не важно, что это. Главное, что мы имеем левый-нижний угол и правый-верхний.)) Я просто ищу оптимальные варианты решения этой задачи. Считайте это так - как вам удобнее.

Comment: Если объекты статичны и не двигаются и сразу заданы все координаты, то они соприкасаются тогда, если a.begin.x = b.end.x(и наоборот) или a.begin.y = b.end.y(и наоборот). Во всех остальных случаях, они либо не прикасаются, либо пересекаются(что не равно из условия - столкновению) Из примера не ясен размер объектов и двигаются ли они.

Comment: @SwaD объекты не статичный - двигаются. Но координаты и размер нам известны, при помощи этого я и считаю координаты углов. Прошу прошения за недопонимание, пересечение тоже считает столкновением. Описанным вами методом я на данный момент и решил задачу, но для множество объектов она работает медленно и поэтому ищу более оптимальный вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пересечение прямоугольников существует при таком соотношении координат:

```
function intersect(a, b) {
  return (a.left <= b.right &&
          b.left <= a.right &&
          a.top => b.bottom &&
          b.top => a.bottom)
}
```

Однако случаи  `Один прямоугольник в другом` требуют отдельной проверки

```
function notinside(a, b) {
  return (((~~(a.left > b.right) + 
           ~~(b.right < a.right) + 
           ~~(a.top < b.top) + 
           ~~(b.bottom > a.bottom)) & 3) > 0)
}
```

Здесь `~~(boolean)` приводит результат сравнения к 0 или 1, и проверяется, что не все четыре результата одинаковы. Проверить JS код мне не на чем, так что написано умозрительно. Есть тонкости, если часть координат совпадает - не знаю, будет ли это вам мешать (если да, то отдельные проверки на `a в b` и `b в a`)

```
if (intersect(a, b) && notinside(a,b))
      прямоугольники пересекаются по сторонам
```

---

Есть ещё такой момент - при создании системы движущихся объектов часто лучше не определять факт столкновения, каждую миллисекунду обсчитывая считая множество пар, а предрассчитывать время, в которое произойдёт столкновение объектов и соответственно изменение направлений.

Comment: Это хорошое решение, почти такую же у себя применил. Но нету ли какие-то трюки с тригонометрией, или что-то такое, чтобы еще оптимизировать этот алгоритм?

Comment: Пересечение ищется оптимально. Вхождение я сократил с 8 сравнений до четырёх. Оно дело несколько портит - а нужно ли оно вообще? Кроме того, в зависимости от задачи можно применить подходящие структуры данных - например, проверять только пересечение с теми прямоугольниками, которые находятся рядом ([пример](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_(%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)))

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если это *вектора* - то можно сравнить четверти этих векторов. Для этого вычисляем **путь** -> **векторные координаты**.

Пример на псевдокоде.

Вход:

```
PathStart1 = {
    start = Point {
        x = A
        y = B
    }
    end = Point {
        x = C
        y = D
    }
}

PathStart2 = {
    start = Point {
        x = E
        y = F
    }
    end = Point {
        x = G
        y = H
    }
}
```

Алгоритм:

```
// Преобразование в вектора
Vector1 = {
    x = C - A
    y = D - B
}
Vector2 = {
    x = G - E
    y = H - F
}

// Проверяем одинаковые ли четверти
ЕСЛИ (sign(Vector1.x) != sign(Vector2.x))
    exit(False)
ИНАЧЕ ЕСЛИ (sign(Vector1.y) != sign(Vector2.y))
    exit(False)
ИНАЧЕ
    exit(True)
```

Выход:

```
True // Если вектора лежат в одной четверти (знаки соответствующих осей у обоих векторов одинаковы)
False // Если вектора лежат в разных четвертях (хоть одина соответствующая проекция на ось имеет отличный знак от второй проекции)
```

Comment: Ещё раз повторюсь, вектор - это просто комплексное число, он не имеет положения в пространстве, только направление и длину. Если вам важны начальные и конечные точки - используйте *пути*.

Comment: а при чём тут четверти?  в задаче нужно определить пересекаются ли прямоугольники

Comment: @ESkri, вопрос был изменён. Изначально там были вектора.

Comment: да, автор по-школьному использует термин "вектор" (в школе учат, что у вектора есть начало и конец).  и что?  при чём тут четверти?  в задаче (и старой версии, и новой) спрашивается про столкновение объектов.

Comment: Я использую термин вектор так как у меня уже был класс вектора и с помощью него было легче всего описать задачу. Речь о пересечении прямоугольников. И да, вопрос не изменился насчет векторов.

Comment: @ESkri в моей школе подобной чуши не учили...

Comment: @andreymal - почему чушь? детям объясняют, что это почти материальный объект, эдакая деревянная палочка, у которой два конца, эту палочку можно приложить к другой палочке для выполнения векторного сложения.  а тебе наверное рассказывали про стрелки часов вместо палочек, поэтому у тебя векторы прибиты гвоздями к нулю.  начинать школьный курс двумерной геометрии с корректного определения векторного пространства над полем - вряд ли уместно

Comment: @ESkri в моей школе учили векторам уже не в таком возрасте, в котором требовалось бы выдумывать какие-то палочки и стрелочки...

Comment: @andreymal - А как? Сразу рассказали, что вектор - это класс эквивалентности направленных отрезков относительно операции параллельного переноса? )))  Или на геометрии в начальной школе вы векторы не проходили, зато на алгебре в последний год обучения вам сразу сказали, что вектор - это матрица размером 1 на N? )))  Люди, обучавшиеся в школе на наглядном материале, имеют развитое воображение и потом пишут на партах ВУЗов фразы типа "каждому лектору в ж. по вектору", а с алгебраическим подходом даже в голову такое не придёт, ведь вектор - это просто столбец чисел, как его...